# Form fill and capture fail sometimes using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to fill the form and take capture of the generated page. So I wrote a CasperJS (This is my first time to use CasperJS) to archive to goal. I read the CasperJS API document but still not sure how to fix the problem.

Below is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var filename = casper.cli.get(0);
var myear = casper.cli.get(1);
var mmon  = casper.cli.get(2);
var stk_no = casper.cli.get(3);

casper.start('http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/STOCK_DAYMAIN.php', function() {
        this.fill("form[name='date_form']", {
                'myear' : myear,
                'mmon'  : mmon,
                'STK_NO': stk_no
        },true);
});

casper.then(function() {
        this.capture(filename);
        this.echo("Saved screenshot of " + (this.getCurrentUrl()) + " to " + filename);

});

casper.run();
```

My command is like

```
casperjs test.js picture.png 2013 12 8271
```

Sometimes no picture file will be generated and it turns out to be failed:

```
Saved screenshot of http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/STOCK_DAY.php to picture.png
```

Sometimes a picture file will be generated and it turns out to be successful:

```
Saved screenshot of http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/genpage/Report201312/201312_F3_1_8_8271.php?STK_NO=8271&myear=2013&mmon=12 to picture.png
```

Why does sometime it work and give the capture but sometimes fail? Why the return value of this.getCurrentUrl() could differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the current URL is `http://www.twse.com.tw/en/trading/exchange/STOCK_DAY/STOCK_DAY.php`, means you are blocked  in the start page and waiting for the redirect, Change your

```
casper.then(function() {
        this.capture(filename);
        this.echo("Saved screenshot of " + (this.getCurrentUrl()) + " to " + filename);

});
```

to:

```
casper.waitForUrl(/Report/, function() {
        this.capture(filename);
        this.echo("Saved screenshot of " + (this.getCurrentUrl()) + " to " + filename);

});
```

`/Report/` means "Report" in your current URL, so your are at the page data queried.